# How to reverse the hide event of a div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a div and a button which i would like to show/hide the div when its clicked:

```
<input type="button" name="info" value="Contact Information" onclick="showDiv()">
<div align="center" id="element" style="display: none;">bla</div>
```

And this piece of script:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('element').style.display = "block";
   if( ... )
   document.getElementById('element').style.display = "none";
}
```

The display style of the div is none,so its hidden.The first line of the js script changes that value into block,so the div its displayed now. Now i need something to reverse the first line,in case the button its triggered again.So i thought a conditional statement will do it,but i have no idea how to build it. Something line : "if the display style its block,execute the code between {}"
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

```js
function toggleDiv(elementId, button, textOn, textOff) {
  var style = document.getElementById(elementId).style;
  if( style.display == "none" ) {
    style.display = "block";
    button.innerHTML = textOn;
  } else {
    style.display = "none";
    button.innerHTML = textOff;
  }
}
```

```html
<button name="info" onclick="toggleDiv('element', this, 'Hide Contact Information', 'Show Contact Information')">Show Contact Information</button>
<div align="center" id="element" style="display: none;">bla</div>
```

---

### Original Answer

---

```
function toggleDiv() {
    if( document.getElementById('element').style.display == "none" ) {
        document.getElementById('element').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('element').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: and in case i also want to change the button name when its clicked? Default is "Show Contact Info" , and if its clicked (when div its displayed) , the name will be "Hide Contact Info" ??

Comment: document.getElementById('buttonId').innerHTML = "Hide Contact Info";

Answer (score 2):

Using the browser DOM directly is very annoying and your solution may not work in all browsers. You should use some javascript framework like jQuery, prototype or mootools. In jQuery what you want to do is as simple as this:

```
$("#element").toggle()
```

If you insist on using raw javascript you can try this:

```
function showDiv() {
   if( document.getElementById('element').style.display == 'block' )
   document.getElementById('element').style.display = "none";
   else
   document.getElementById('element').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="info" value="Contact Information" onclick="showDiv()">
<div align="center" id="element" style="display: none;">bla</div>
<script>
function showDiv() {
   var div = document.getElementById('element').style.display;
   if( div == 'block' )
      document.getElementById('element').style.display = "none";
    else 
    document.getElementById('element').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```